# Grease Pencil Line-art layer: How to place it into a render pass / view layer?

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

This is the closest I get to have Grease Pencil Line-art modifier as a render pass:

[image]

But it's very aliased and not a very good approach. How to do it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps how to render pure Grease Pencil layers into view layers:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]